# How to Mock Request Headers in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is the sample code of what I have written

```
    String bearerToken="Bearer "+ token; 
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 
    request.addHeader("Authorization",bearerToken); 
    request.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); 
    HttpResponse response=client.execute(request); 
    System.out.println("Response Code:" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

How can I mock these request headers in java? How do I mock Authorization and response?.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to mock bearertoken how can I mock that ?

Comment: @DivyashreeR I would suggest you try and understand concept of Mocking different objects to test a java class by reading more about it online. Based on your snipped I feel you should be looking to mock the HttpClient so that you can control/customize interactions made by that object to test your implementation

Comment: @DivyashreeR you do not mock a value. You are using term `mock` non conventionally so can you please explain what you want to achieve? You want to  `mock bearertoken` in order to do what?

Comment: I am hitting a rest end point using httpclient so to mock that rest end point and to mock the response which I am fetching from that endpoint. In need to mock the request headers so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your unit test class you need to mock client:

```
@Mock
private HttpClient client;
```

Then you tell mockito in @Before method to actually create your mocks by

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(YourTestClass);
```

Then in your test method, you can mock what execute() method should return:

```
Mockito.when(client.execute(any()/* or wahtever you want here */)).thenReturn(your json object);
```

Mocking your HttpClient is preferred more because there may be some times when if you make an actual call to the rest API after mocking your headers the API may return unwanted response[when the service is down or restarting].

But if you still want to mock a private field you can do it using

```
ReflectionUtils.setField()
```

Comment: Can you please help me to write test case for the method mentioned above.

Comment: Did you try following the steps

Comment: yes but not understanding how to mock the JSON response and perform Assertion on it

Comment: I am very new to Junits and mockito could you please help me to write for that above method to mock a JSON response.

Comment: You can use Jackson library's Object mapper to map a json to an object which can be used to mock your response .https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: Whatever your response is create a Json file with the expected response read the response into an Object and use Mockito.when(client.execute(any()/* or wahtever you want here */)).thenReturn(your json object);